# Removing slant horizontal lines in image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, line

[image: original image]

I have an image where I have a horizontal line underlying the text ; after applying through various techniques in order  a. HoughLineP and HoughLine and this code

```
 image = cv2.imread('D:\\detect_words.jpg')
 gray = 255 - cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 for row in range(gray.shape[0]):
    avg = np.average(gray[row, :] > 16)
    if avg > 0.25:
        cv2.line(image, (0, row), (gray.shape[1]-1, row), (0, 0, 255))
        cv2.line(gray, (0, row), (gray.shape[1]-1, row), (0, 0, 0), 1)
  cv2.imwrite('D:\\words\\final_removed.jpg',image)
```

I am able to get to this 
[image: after processing]

after this phase; I am applying erosion and dilation

```
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8) 
img_erosion = cv2.erode(255-gray, kernel, iterations=1) 
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img_erosion, kernel, iterations=1) 
cv2.imwrite('D:\\words\\final_removed4.jpg',255-img_dilation)
```

[image: final image after dilation and erosion]

My question is; removing the horizontal lines although removes but there is pixel loss for words; and not all the horizontal lines are removed. Is there a novel approch where this loss can be minimized and all horizontal lines are removed (here the horizontal lines above AGE is still present).

Comment: Lower the 0.25 in avg > 0.25, so that t filters out smaller length lines. Or filter on actual line length. Once the lines are remove you can try morphology open to fill in the gaps in the text.

Comment: Is the top image in OP detect_words.jpg or just part of it? It seems like the line thickness of the white line you draw isn't thick enough to completely erase the bottom line.Regrettably line thickness is an integer so increasing to 2 might be too much. So you might have to scale the whole image so that thickness 2 is just right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove noisy lines from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028493/remove-noisy-lines-from-an-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to get binary image
- Create horizontal kernel and morph open to detect lines
- Find contours and draw in detected lines

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

```
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Now we create a special horizontal kernel to detect horizontal lines then morph open to obtain a mask of the detected lines

[image]

```
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (45,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
```

Here's the detected lines drawn on the original image

[image]

From here we find contours on this mask and draw them in to effectively remove the horizontal lines to get our result

[image]

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 3)
```

Now that the horizontal lines are removed, to repair the text, you can try `cv2.MORPH_CLOSE` with a `cv2.MORPH_CROSS` kernel and experiment with various kernel sizes. There is a tradeoff between dilating too much to close the holes as the detail in the text will be lost. Another approach is to use [image inpainting](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) to fill in the holes. I'll leave this step to you

Full code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (45,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('detected_lines', detected_lines)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. How do i connect the dots of missing A, like i am doing erode and dilate but what matrix to pass in order to smoothen that.

Comment: You can use `cv2.morphologyEx()` and try experimenting with [these matrixes](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) and various kernel sizes