# Removing curved line from captcha

Tags: python, captcha, opencv, simplecaptcha

I am trying to read a captcha generated by SimpleCaptcha:

[image: captcha]

I've managed to remove the gradient and color:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import PyDIP as dip
import pytesseract

img = cv.imread('capt.jpg')
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

[image: captcha bw]

However, I can't remove the curved line or fill the letters.

I have tried the code from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028493/remove-noisy-lines-from-an-image) and got this:

```
lines = dip.PathOpening(img, length=400, mode={'constrained'})
img = img-lines
img = 255 - img
```

[image: No lines]

```
lines = np.array(lines)
```

[image: Detected lines]

And with this [other method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274961/removing-horizontal-lines-in-image-opencv-python-matplotlib) I get:

```
# image is the previous img

gray = cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

horizontal_kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (25,1))
detected_lines = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv.findContours(detected_lines, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

repair_kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1,6))
result = 255 - cv.morphologyEx(255 - image, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel, iterations=1)

# results:
```

[image: No lines]

```
# detected_lines:
```

[image: Detected lines]

I'm trying to read the text with:

```
captcha_val=pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

This is [the source](https://apps2.mef.gob.pe/consulta-vfp-webapp/Captcha.jpg) of captcha. Any help?

Comment: The text and line are in two different colors. Maybe you could use that to remove the line?

Comment: Sometimes, the text and line have the same color.